# Multiple mismatches in DNA search sequence regex

Tags: python, regex, biopython, dna-sequence

I have written this barbaric script to create permutations of a string of characters that contain n (up to n=4) $'s in all possible combinations of positions within the string.  I will eventually `.replace('$','(\\w)')` to use for mismatches in a dna search sequence.  Because of the way I wrote the script, some of the permutations have less than the requested number of $'s.  I then wrote a script to remove them, but it doesn't seem to be effective, and each time I run the removal script, it removes more of the unwanted permutations.  In the code pasted below, you will see that I test the function with a simple sequence with 4 mismatches.  I then run a series of removal scripts that count how many expressions are removed each time...in my experience, it takes about 8 times to remove all expressions with less than 4 wild-card $'s. I have a couple questions about this:

1. Is there a built in function for searches with 'n' mismatches?  Maybe even in biopython?  So far, I've seen the Paul_McGuire_regex function:
   [Search for string allowing for one mismatch in any location of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420412/search-for-string-allowing-for-one-mismatch-in-any-location-of-the-string),
   which seems only to generate 1 mismatch. I must admit, I don't fully understand all of the code in the remainining functions on that page, as I am a very new coder.
2. Since I see this as a good exercise for me, is there a better way to write this entire script?...Can I iterate Paul_McGuire_regex function as many times as I need?
3. Most perplexing to me, why won't the removal script work 100% the first time?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

```
def Mismatch(Search,n):
    List = []
    SearchL = list(Search)
    if n > 4:
        return("Error: Maximum of 4 mismatches")
    for i in range(0,len(Search)):
        if n == 1:
            SearchL_i = list(Search)
            SearchL_i[i] = '$'
            List.append(''.join(SearchL_i))
        if n > 1:
            for j in range (0,len(Search)):
                if n == 2:
                    SearchL_j = list(Search)
                    SearchL_j[i] = '$'
                    SearchL_j[j] = '$'
                    List.append(''.join(SearchL_j))
                if n > 2:
                    for k in range(0,len(Search)):
                        if n == 3:
                            SearchL_k = list(Search)
                            SearchL_k[i] = '$'
                            SearchL_k[j] = '$'
                            SearchL_k[k] = '$'
                            List.append(''.join(SearchL_k))
                        if n > 3:
                            for l in range(0,len(Search)):
                                if n ==4:
                                    SearchL_l = list(Search)
                                    SearchL_l[i] = '$'
                                    SearchL_l[j] = '$'
                                    SearchL_l[k] = '$'
                                    SearchL_l[l] = '$'
                                    List.append(''.join(SearchL_l))
    counter=0
    for el in List:
        if el.count('$') < n:
            counter+=1
            List.remove(el)
    return(List) 

List_RE = Mismatch('abcde',4)

counter = 0
for el in List_RE:
    if el.count('$') < 4:
        List_RE.remove(el)
        counter+=1

print("Filter2="+str(counter))
```

Answer (score 3):

We can do away with questions 2 and 3 by answering question 1, but understanding question 3 is important so I'll do that first and then show how you can avoid it entirely:

### Question 3

As to question 3, it's because when you loop over a list in python and make changes to it *within the loop*, the list that you loop over changes.

From the [python docs on control flow (for statement section)](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html):

> It is **not safe** to modify the sequence being iterated over in the loop
>   (this can only happen for mutable sequence types, such as lists).

Say your list is `[a,b,c,d]` and you loop through it with `for el in List`.
Say `el` is currently `a` and you do `List.remove(el)`.

Now, your list is `[b,c,d]`. However, the iterator points to the second element in the list (since it's done the first), which is now `c`.
In essence, you've skipped `b`. So the problem is that you are modifying the list you are iterating over.

There are a few ways to fix this: if your `List` is not expensive to duplicate, you could make a copy. So iterate over `List[:]` but remove from `List`.

But suppose it's expensive to make copies of `List` all the time.
Then what you do is iterate over it **backwards**. Note the `reversed` below:

```
for el in reversed(List):
    if el.count('$') < n:
        counter+=1
        List.remove(el)
return(List)
```

In the example above, suppose we iterate backwards over `List`.
The iterator starts at `d`, and then goes to `c`.
Suppose we remove `c`, so that `List=[a,b,d]`.
Since the iterator is going *backwards*, it now points to element `b`, so we haven't skipped anything.

Basically, this avoids modifying bits of the list you have yet to iterate over.

### Questions 1 & 2

If I understand your question correctly, you basically want to choose `n` out of `m` positions, where `m` is the length of the string (`abcde`), and place a '$' in each of these `n` positions.

In that case, you can use the `itertools` module to do that.

```
import itertools
def Mismatch(Search,n):
    SearchL = list(Search)
    List     = [] # hold output
    # print list of indices to replace with '$'
    idxs = itertools.combinations(range(len(SearchL)),n)        
    # for each combination `idx` in idxs, replace str[idx] with '$':
    for idx in idxs:
        str = SearchL[:] # make a copy
        for i in idx:
            str[i]='$'
        List.append( ''.join(str) ) # convert back to string
    return List
```

Let's look at how this works:

1. turn the `Search` string into a list so it can be iterated over, create empty `List` to hold results.
2. `idxs = itertools.combinations(range(len(SearchL)),n)` says "find all subsets of length n in the set `[0,1,2,3,...,length-of-search-string -1]`.
   Try

   ```
   idxs = itertools.combinations(range(5),4)
   for idx in idxs: 
       print idx
   ```

   to see what I mean.
3. Each element of `idxs` is a tuple of `n` indices from 0 to `len(SearchL)-1` (e.g. `(0,1,2,4)`. Replace the i'th character of `SearchL` with a '$' for each `i` in the tuple.
4. Convert the result back into a string and add it to `List`.

As an example:

```
Mismatch('abcde',3)
['$$$de', '$$c$e', '$$cd$', '$b$$e', '$b$d$', '$bc$$', 'a$$$e', 'a$$d$', 'a$c$$', 'ab$$$']
Mismatch('abcde',4) # note, the code you had made lots of duplicates.
['$$$$e', '$$$d$', '$$c$$', '$b$$$', 'a$$$$']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering question 3!  That was a very lucid explanation that helps me understand python list iterations a bit better.  The reversed solution is very nice!

Comment: Aww....great.  I figured there was something like itertools out there.  Thanks so much for not only the solutions but the thoughtful explanations!