# 1-mismatch regular expression

Tags: python, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search for string allowing for one mismatch in any location of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420412/search-for-string-allowing-for-one-mismatch-in-any-location-of-the-string)

I am given a string `s` and a string `t`. Is there a regular expression to find all occurrences of `t` inside `s` with *at most one mismatched character*. (At most one character from `t` is allowed to be substituted by another.)

Comment: Please add some example data to play with, it makes things easier

Comment: @Robjong: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420412/search-for-string-allowing-for-one-mismatch-in-any-location-of-the-string) is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: i'm no expert on this subject, but you may be able to use a variant of this that allows up to 1 mismatch: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm

Comment: @Randomblue - if you can cite another SO question that covers this exact same topic, shouldn't this be closed as a duplicate?  I posted a couple of possible solutions in the other question, including a pyparsing solution that handles not just single mismatch, but also n-mismatch. Did you try any of those?

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: Yeah, it should. I only noticed after posting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't necessarily do this with regex.  You can use Levenshtein distance.

```
>>> import Levenshtein
>>> s = "spam ham and eggs"
>>> t = "ram"
>>> for i,_ in enumerate(s): 
...   s_ = s[i:i+len(t)]
...   if Levenshtein.distance(s_, t) == 1:
...     print s_
... 
pam
ham
```

Comment: sounds suboptimal. Levenshtein will keep counting even after 1 error

Comment: yeah it will, but Levenshtein distance is pretty fast and it may not be performance critical code anyway.  premature optimisation and all that.

Comment: except that in his comments he said he was trying to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420412/search-for-string-allowing-for-one-mismatch-in-any-location-of-the-string which is a rather large data set. i don't think this is premature.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely. For example, if `t` is `"abcde"`, then one such regex is

```
.bcde|a.cde|ab.de|abc.e|abcd.
```

That said, this is almost certainly *not* the best or most efficient way to do this, especially if `t` is at all big. (If it is big, then you can improve its performance somewhat by reformulating it as

```
.bcde|a(?:.cde|b(?:.de|c(?:.e|d.)))
```

or perhaps as

```
a(?:b(?:c(?:d.|.e)|.de)|.cde)|.bcde
```

but it's still not the best approach.)