# Regex substring one mismatch in any location of string

Tags: python, pattern-matching, string-matching

Can someone explain why the code below returns an empty list:

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.findall("(SS){e<=1}", "PSSZ")
>>> m
[]
```

I am trying to find the total number of occurrences of `SS` (and incorporating the possibility of **up to one mismatch**) within `PSSZ`.

I saw a similar example of code here: [Search for string allowing for one mismatch in any location of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420412/search-for-string-allowing-for-one-mismatch-in-any-location-of-the-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `e<=` chars present inside the range quantifier. Range quantifier must be of ,

- `{n}` . Repeats the previous token `n` number of times.
- `{min,max}` Repeats the previous token from min to max times.

It would be,

```
m = re.findall("(SS){1}", "PSSZ")
```

or

```
m = re.findall(r'SS','PSSZ')
```

**Update:**

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?=(S.|.S))', 'PSSZ')
['PS', 'SS', 'SZ']
```

Comment: This only gives `SS` (one instance), not `PS` or `SZ`, where there is one mismatch.

Comment: @warship .. didn't you ask for the number of occurrence of `SS` ?

Comment: It should also return `SS`.  Hopefully, with something simple like the `{1}` notation, this would be much more elegant.

Comment: Thank you, very interesting.  I assume this is the most concise way to do it.  How would you go about working with triple character strings such as `SSZ`, would the regex notation change?  Perhaps you can post an update.