# Scaling regex on big strings in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, pattern-matching, string-matching

I'm trying to take [Regex substring one mismatch in any location of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364367/regex-substring-one-mismatch-in-any-location-of-string#31364373) and turn it into a big data situation where I can:

Match all instances of big substrings such as `SSQPSPSQSSQPSS` (and allowing *only one* possible mismatch within this substring) to a much larger string such as `SSPQQQQPSSSSQQQSSQPSPSQSSQPSSQPPSSSSQPSPSQSSQPSSSSQPSPSQSSQPSSSSQPSPSQSSQPSSSSQSPSSQSSQPSS`.

In reality, my substrings and the strings that I match them to are in the hundreds and sometimes even thousands of letters and I wish to incorporate the possibility of mismatches.

How can I scale the regex notation of [Regex substring one mismatch in any location of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364367/regex-substring-one-mismatch-in-any-location-of-string#31364373) to solve my big data problems?  Is there an efficient way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this,

```
>>> s = "SSPQQQQPSSSSQQQSSQPSPSQSSQPSSQPPSSSSQPSPSQSSQPSSSSQPSPSQSSQPSSSSQPSPSQSSQPSSSSQSPSSQSSQPSS"
>>> re.findall(r'(?=(SSQPSPSQSSQPSS|[A-Z]SQPSPSQSSQPSS|S[A-Z]QPSPSQSSQPSS|SS[A-Z]PSPSQSSQPSS))', s)
['SSQPSPSQSSQPSS', 'SSQPSPSQSSQPSS', 'SSQPSPSQSSQPSS', 'SSQPSPSQSSQPSS']
```

Likwise add pattern with replacing remaining chars with `[A-Z]`.