# Python regex - what happened to {e<=1}?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I was just looking at a thread on here where I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10986521/13339891). I tried it on my python 3 compiler, but for some reason it didn't work. And in the official python documentation for regex I can't seem to find anything for {e<=1}. Did it get removed or replaced?

For reference, here is the code and its output:

```py
>>> import re
>>> m = re.findall("(AA){e<=1}", "CAAG")
>>> m
[]
```

Comment: The answer explains that *"Python [regex](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) library supports fuzzy regular expression matching"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you are looking at does not use Python's built-in `re` module, but a third-party `regex` library instead: https://pypi.org/project/regex/.