# string-match problem 

Tags: string, algorithm, perl, substring

> > EDIT 2: I managed to find the solution with suffix trees `Tree::Suffix` perl package. Thanks to MarcoS for the `trie` idea. I figured out from that, that suffix trees could be used as well. The `Tree::Trie` perl package is implemented as hash of hashes and I guess that's the reason it slow. I tried it and then went back to `Tree::Suffix`. Thanks to all others for their links to different algorithms. I am already trying to write code for every algorithm mentioned here myself as a learning process
> >
> > EDIT 1: I changed the title from `perl string-match problem` to `string-match problem`.

Suppose that I have two strings, say,
`S1 = ACGAGGATAGTATGCCACACAATGAGTACCCGTAC`
`S2 = CAGTATTGCACGTTGTAAAGTTACCCAGGTACGATGACAGTGCGTGAGCATACGAGGATAGTATGCCA`

I initially wanted to check for the occurrence of string S1 (with no or 1 mismatch) in S2. And I have already written the `perl` code for that.

Now, I would like to develop on it to

> 1) Search for k-mismatches of S1 in S2.
>   2) Search for the occurrence of a `prefix` (yes, prefix, not suffix), of S1 in S2. If you look at the example, the string: `ACGAGGATAGTATGCCA` occurs at the end of S2 which is the beginning of S1.
>   3) If possible, search for the prefix with k-mismatches.

The catch is that I have about 100 million such S2 strings. S1 however remains the same and is of a defined constant length for a given problem. Is there an efficient algorithm in the literature that I could use for this problem of mine?

S1 varies between 50 and 80 characters. Also, I am mostly interested in solving `problem 2` at first.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I can't believe it would be efficient to write that in perl unless you can find a native module to implement the k-mismatch algorithm.

Comment: Could a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) be helpful for your purposes?

Comment: Perhaps see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672782/fastest-way-to-find-mismatch-positions-between-two-strings-of-the-same-length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to modify the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

For approximate matching, have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitap_algorithm as used in agrep.